# How to correctly serialize C# long number using controller's Json method in Asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

Mvc Controller.Json method serializes long number 3458764513820540917 to 3458764513820541000. I need POCO with int64 property. How can I serialize C# long to json string "3458764513820540917"?

Comment: I think you should phrase this as a question!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All numbers in JavaScript are, in fact, [64-bit floats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision).

It looks to me like you're hitting the range/precision limitations of that format on the client-side, rather than this being a problem with (de)serialisation.

Comment: Ok. I don't any calculation on that number in javascript. Is it possible to serialize long integer to string?

Comment: @Baurzhan: I should think so. It all depends on what/how you're serialising on the server-side. Something as simple as a `ToString` call on your long value might do the trick.

Comment: I have class with property of type long. On server side i call method Json(<instance of class>)